# Сдвиг элемента за границу экрана

Tags: jquery, css

Как сдвинуть элемент за границу страницы так, чтобы край элемента выступал на определённое количество пикселей?

Когда делаю так:

```
$('.comments').animate({ right: "945px" }, 500);
```

То всё работает. А когда пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$('.comments').animate({ right: "calc(100% - 30px)" }, 500);
```

или так:

```
$('.comments').animate({ right: "100%" - 30рх }, 500);
```

ничего не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
comments = $('.comments');
parentWidth = comments.parent().width(); // узнаем 100%
comments.animate({right:parentWidth - 30},500);
```

Comment: Всё работает как часики. Спасибо Вам огромное!